# Animation jerky when magnifier images on Chrome (on Firefox is fluid)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, animation, gsap, image-scaling

I am making a small web-app using javascript and GSAP.

The operation is very simple, I click on the preview and **it zooms the right image** into a specific coordinate. With the zoomed image is run activate the drag of the image.

The problem is that when I start it **on chrome** the first few clicks have a **super lag** and if the page is refreshed it returns the same problem every time.

The image is very heavy but more than that I can't compress it and I don't want to lose resolution.

This will run locally on the machine with touch screen so I don't care about the weight of the images, hovering etc... I was thinking of using electron but being chromium based it gives the same problems.

I tried various methods and libraries: anime.js, velocity.js, canvas but the result doesn't change. The only really performing one is to do it from CSS but then you lose control over the areas to zoom.

Strangely **if you open the link on Firefox the rendering of the image is super smooth**. It's actually like firfox downsampling during the animation and then loading the rest of the image, but making the experience less jerky.

My question is:

- is it possible to change chrome in the rendering method of images (inside config) and make it more like firefox?
- What can I do to make the animation smoother on Chrome as well?
- is there a way to force images into cache?

Here the **LINK** - https://animdrops.xyz/static/02-magnifier/

Here a simple example of the same problem (try the difference between chrome and firefox)

https://codepen.io/matt8629/pen/OJdJbXr
FIRST LOAD PAGES IS A BIT LONG!

And here zoom code

```
gsap.to(zoomImage, {
  scale: targetScale,
  x: isZoomed ? 0 : deltaX * targetScale,
  y: isZoomed ? 0 : deltaY * targetScale,
  duration: 1,
  ease: 'power2.inOut',
  onComplete: () => {
    console.log('zoom end');
  },
});
```